# Jackson @JsonSubTypes - Polymorphic deserialization with generics

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, polymorphic-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this json body that I don't have any control over. Because the API I'm calling could provide different "data" (arrays of objects) depending on the "method" value, I thought of polymorphism and using `@JsonSubTypes`. However the current set up gives me an error. I'm already using generics for another case which where "data" is an object and that works fine. But I'm not able to solve this with arrays of objects.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException:
> Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array
> to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class
> demo.common.dto.response.data.AccountLedgerResponse

Not sure what it is referring to since "data" json property starts with **"["**.

**JSON**

```
{
    "version": "1.1",
    "result": {
        "signature": "lCteM8iCg++7uyF...TYoY/mc7eUQ6FWNPg==",
        "method": "AccountLedger",
        "data": [{
            "userid": "3839426635",
            "datestamp": "2014-01-30 13:28:45.652299+01",
            "orderid": "3209647863",
            "accountname": "SUSPENSE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_FUNDS_SWEDEN_ESSE",
            "messageid": "133921",
            "transactiontype": "User deposit of client funds to CLIENT_FUNDS_SWEDEN_ESSE",
            "currency": "EUR",
            "amount": "5.00000000000000000000",
            "gluepayid": "3209647863"
        }, {
            "accountname": "TRANSACTION_FEE_BANK_DEPOSIT",
            "orderid": "3209647863",
            "userid": "3839426635",
            "datestamp": "2014-01-30 13:28:45.652299+01",
            "messageid": "133921",
            "transactiontype": "User deposit of client funds to CLIENT_FUNDS_SWEDEN_ESSE",
            "currency": "SEK",
            "amount": "-3.01",
            "gluepayid": "3209647863"
        }],
        "uuid": "9e4345db-6093-bb35-07d3-e335f1e28793"
    }
}
```

The expected object:

```
public record ResultList<T extends ResponseData>(

        @JsonProperty("signature")
        String signature,

        @JsonProperty("uuid")
        UUID uuid,

        @JsonProperty("method")
        Method method,

        @JsonProperty("data")
        @JsonTypeInfo(
                use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
                include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY,
                property = "method")
        @JsonSubTypes({
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AccountLedgerResponse.class, name = "AccountLedger")
        })
        List<T> data) {

    @Builder
    public ResultList {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List` type can't be identified.

Your `TypeInfo` for `AccountLedger` should identify a class that contains an array of `AccountLedger`.

You have to have a class that contains the list, something like:

```
AccountLedgerList {
    List<AccountLedger> data;
}
```

and then your `method` identifies the `List` object type:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AccountLedgerList.class, name = "AccountLedger")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. :) 

But wouldn't also the `AccountLedgerList` also be an object wrapping the list in this case?

Comment: Okay, it seems like it works thanks to you :) But I had to basically make AccountLedgerList implement List in order to make it work. Was that what you were trying to imply? Or are there other ways instead of having to implement List?

Comment: Yes, JsonSubTypes.Type has to identify the class to be used, not the type that is contained in the List. It is just how I like to code it: `DtoType` and `DtoTypeList`. But as you said `DtoTypeList extends List<DtoType>` is functionally the same .